# Siva Purana Transliteration - Not the same as Translation

Tags: shiva

Are there any Siva Purana books with english Transliteration? This is not the same as translation. This would be the Sanskrit sloka written in english. I could only find this book, but thats only the Uttarakhanda -

https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/siva-purana-uttarakhanda-text-with-english-translation-and-introduction-IDG617/

Comment: For a text like Shiva Purana, I don't think anyone would publish a book with English transliteration & translation of shlokas. ISKCON did it with SB and BG most likely to cater to Western audience but I doubt if Shiva Purana has such a following in the West. Even the book you mention [uses](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/books-2017/idg617p.jpg) Devanagari script for shlokas.

Comment: @sv. thank you for your response. Yes, I have the BG with me and I do agree with you on the western following. There are many translations of the Siva Purana, J. L Sastri's one seems to be very popular, but its all english. While I understand some sanskrit and pali, I never learned the script. I learned it via the script of my mother tongue (sinhala from Sri Lanka).

Comment: You can keep checking the [GRETIL site](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.html#Pur) for English transliteration of Shiva Purana. Right now they only have [Book 1](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/sivap1_u.htm) and [Book 7](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/sivap7_u.htm) transliterated.

Comment: Thank you @sv. I have seen this. I was planning on reaching out to them asking why only the 1 and 7 done. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the form of PDF but English transliteration of Shiva Purana is available online at wisdomlimb:-[Shiva Purana (Sanskrit)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit)

Maybe this could help you.

Comment: thank you so much ! This is exactly what I needed. Amazing. !

Comment: If you like the answer, you can upvote/accept the answer by clicking on ✔️ @SandunPanthangi